# tapping on an icon in tab navigation to scroll to top of a list isn't working in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a bottom tab navigation in my React native app, and in the the first tab screen I have a component that contains a flatlist basically, and I want when the user taps on that tab Icon to scroll to top (basically like instagram). I tried several implementation where I used `scrollToIndex` and `scrollToOffset` and tried using the `useScrollToTop` in react-navigation and here is my implementation:

(TabNavigator.js):

```
<Tab.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeNavigation}
  options={{
    tabBarButton: (props) => (
      <TouchableOpacity
        {...props}
        style={[...props.style, styles.buttonStyle]}
        disabled={currentShapeAnim.name === 'home'}
        onPress={() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            navigation.navigate('Home');
          }, 550);
          selectTab('home', jumpHome, bounceHome, wp(35));
        }}>
        {!hideHome && (
          <Shape icon="e-home" shapeAnimations={[bounceHome]} />
        )}
        <Shape icon="f-home" shapeAnimations={[bounceHome, jumpHome]} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  }}
/>
... // other screens
```

and in my Home Component:

```
 const recipeScroll = useRef(null);
 useScrollToTop(recipeScroll);
...
...
<FlatList
        ref={recipeScroll}
        style={{marginLeft: wp(2), width: '100%', height: hp(20)}}
        data={meals}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        horizontal
        scrollEnabled
        renderItem={({item}) => <MealCard item={item} {...item} />}
```

Comment: did you fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

try maybe to scroll to the first index or item.

by scrolltoindex function